# How can I get the selected item from a Telerik UI for ASP.NET Core DropDownList

Tags: telerik, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I'm using a `kendo-dropdownlist` tag helper from the Telerik UI for ASP.NET Core library. So far I have been able to bind the values that can be selected, but I can't figure out how to get the selected item when a post request is sent.

I have a login form:

```
@page
@model PITS.Areas.Authentication.Pages.Login2Model
@{
}

<form method="post">
    <input class="form-control k-textbox" asp-for="UserName" type="text" />
    <input class="form-control k-textbox" asp-for="Password" type="password" />
    <kendo-dropdownlist name="administraties"
                        filter="FilterType.Contains"
                        placeholder="Selecteer Administratie"
                        style="width: 100%;"
                        bind-to="Model.Organizations">
    </kendo-dropdownlist>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" value="Login">
</form>
```

and a PageModel

```
public class Login2Model : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [BindProperty]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [BindProperty]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Organizations { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        this.Organizations = _getOrganizations();
    }

    private IList<SelectListItem> _getOrganizations()
    {
        return new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem {Value = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Text = "Google"},
            new SelectListItem {Value = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Text = "Apple"},
            new SelectListItem {Value = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Text = "Microsoft"}
        };
    }
}
```

I would expect an attribute on the `kendo-dropdownlist` taghelper but I haven't found it yet. Could someone tell me how to get the selected item?

Answer (score 0):

This assumes you are using Razor.

Use the "for" property to bind the kendo-dropdownlist to a page model property.

```
for="MySelection"
```

Then in your page model.

```
  public string MySelection { get; set; }
```